# Selection Sort Recurrence Relation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, time-complexity, recurrence

up front this is a homework question but I am having a difficult time understanding recurrence relations. I've scoured the internet for examples and they are very vague to me. I understand that recurrence relations for recursive algorithms don't have a set way of handling each one but I am lost at how to understand these. Here's the algorithm I have to work with:

```
void selectionSort(int array[]) {
   sort(array, 0); 
} 

void sort(int[] array, int i) {
   if (i < array.length - 1) 
   { 
      int j = smallest(array, i);    T(n) 
      int temp = array[i]; 
      array[i] = array[j]; 
      array[j] = temp; 
      sort(array, i + 1);    T(n)
   } 
} 

int smallest(int[] array, int j)     T(n - k)
{ 
   if (j == array.length - 1) 
      return array.length - 1; 
   int k = smallest(array, j + 1); 
   return array[j] < array[k] ? j : k; 
}
```

So from what I understand this is what I'm coming up with: T(n) = T(n – 1) +cn + c
The T(n-1) represents the recursive function of sort and the added cn represents the recursive function of smallest which should decrease as n decreases since it's called only the amount of times that are remaining in the array each time. The constant multiplied by n is the amount of time to run the additional code in smallest and the additional constant is the amount of time to run the additional code in sort. Is this right? Am I completely off? Am I not explaining it correctly? Also the next step is to create a recursion tree out of this but I don't see this equation as the form T(n) = aT(n/b) + c which is the form needed for the tree if I understand this right. Also I don't see how my recurrence relation would get to n^2 if it is correct. This is my first post too so I apologize if I did something incorrect here. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to compute the time complexity is to model the time complexity of each function with a separate recurrence relation.

We can model the time complexity of the function `smallest` with the recurrence relation `S(n) = S(n-1)+O(1)`, `S(1)=O(1)`. This obviously solves to `S(n)=O(n)`.

We can model the time complexity of the `sort` function with `T(n) = T(n-1) + S(n) + O(1)`, `T(1)=O(1)`. The `S(n)` term comes in because we call `smallest` within the function `sort`. Because we know that `S(n)=O(n)` we can write `T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n)`, and writing out the recurrence we get `T(n)=O(n)+O(n-1)+...+O(1)=O(n^2)`.

So the total running time is `O(n^2)`, as expected.

Comment: So my answer was almost there with the T(n) = T(n-1) + cn + c? That's good to know that I'm kind of understanding it. Would it be more correct to write O(n) or ϴ(n) since they would be interchangeable in this case? or would they? This time complexity is rough for me. Also I hate to be a pest but how does the recurrence become n^2 from that? It seems like it would be something between (n < time-complexity < n^2).

Comment: Well, one way to see that the sum O(1)+...+O(n-1)+O(n) becomes O(n^2) is to recall that 1+2+3+...+n = n*(n+1)/2 = (n^2+n)/2 = O(n^2). From this you can infer that O(1)+...+O(n) also sums to O(n^2). Yes it is the case that T(n)=Theta(n^2) which implies T(n)=O(n^2). The time complexity is quadratic because of these reasons; it is not between n and n^2, at least not in the sense that it is n^a for 1 < a < 2;

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! So the recursion tree... should have only one branch at each level too right? Since these functions do not branch at any point

Comment: Yes, exactly, the call tree of thhe function `smallest` would be a list. But the call tree of the function `sort` would have at each node a subtree that would correspond to the call tree of the function `smallest`. So the size of this whole tree is `O(n^2)`. Does this make sense?

Comment: So you're saying that at each node, not only would it have the next node of the sort call but at the first node it would branch to 4 tail nodes of smallest, then the next sort node would branch to 3 tail nodes of smallest, then 2 and 1 for the next 2 nodes respectively?

Comment: Yes, that would be the case when the input would be an array of size 4. Do you see why this is the case?

Comment: Yes, very much so. Your explanation has helped me tremendously. I wish I could upvote your response as well as marking it the answer because you have no idea how much this helped.

Comment: Great! I am glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

In selection sort algo

Our outer loop runs for n- 1 times (n is the length of the array) so n-1 passes would be made... and then element is compared with other elements ....so n-1 comparisons

T(n)=T(n-1) + n-1

Which can be proved as O(n^2) by solving the particular relation ..